# I am running a private sub in a worksheet. Can I click something to enable/disable it? i.e. Can I program a button?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code. It is a function that makes it so that when I click a single unlocked cell, it increases the value by one. I am having a problem getting it to always run. Sometimes it runs, sometimes I have to open up the code and press enter after the last END SUB. What I want is a button that refreshes this code so that the VBA works.

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer

Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim Key As Integer

     If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

     Key = GetKeyState(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN)

     If Key And 1 Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
           Target.Value = Target.Value + 1
           Application.EnableEvents = False
           Target.Resize(1, 2).Select
           Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using the mouse events? Is this to ensure it's not from moving there in arrow keys?

Comment: It ensures me that there is less likelihood to fail, but I changed to the script below, which seems to be working better. Thank you for your wisdom enderland.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about this simplified code that works for me ?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  Cancel = True
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

  If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = Target.Value + 1
    Target.Resize(1, 2).Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed my files to this and it seems to work nicely. Thank you! Now I just ran into another problem in which a few of my forms, the sums are not auto summing (which is very strange).